# Adding Oak Flavor/character to beer

Tags: ingredients, oak, flavor, techniques, additives

Short of buying an oak barrel, what forms of oak are available to the homebrewer for getting oak into yuor beer?

Are they available with different levels of toast?
Are some forms easier to sanitize that others?
Do some take more time or less time to get flavor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen a great picture of an oak table leg sticking out the top of a carboy. Wish I could find it.

BYO [covered this question](http://www.byo.com/stories/techniques/article/indices/8-aging/1192-oak-alternatives) in depth. So I won't plagiarize everything here.

- Oak Essence and Powder
- Oak Chips
- Oak Cubes
- Staves and Spirals

Comment: Oak chips have given me the most favorable flavor (with the suggestion of whiskey for sanitization in this question: http://brewadvice.com/questions/244/sterilizing-and-adding-homebrew-additives)

Comment: It might be covered under "staves and spirals", but I have heard to use toasted oak dowel rods. I am trying this right now in a Lambic.